# correct marshalling of c++ structure in c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I have this structure in C++ that I need to be converted to C#, so I can create this structure from a byte[].

```
struct  TRANS_RECORD_DATA {
    int size, code;
    int     ThrowItemCount;
    int     ItemCount;
    int     ItemSubStart;
    int     DataSize;
    BYTE    Data[sizeof(sRECORD_ITEM) * 200]; // sizeof(sRECORD_ITEM) = 548
};
```

The C# version:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
 struct TRANS_RECORD_DATA {
    public int size, code;
        public int ThrowItemCount;
        public int ItemCount;
        public int ItemSubStart;
        public int DataSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 548*200)]
        public byte[] Data;
    };
```

I am using this generic function to give me the structure from the byte array:

```
T ByteArrayToStructure<T>(byte[] bytes) where T : struct
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
    T stuff = (T) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof (T));
    handle.Free();
    return stuff;
}
```

But it is giving me:

> AccessViolation Exception.

I belive I know why but I don't know how to solve it. The `byte[]` I have, that needs to be mapped into the struct, does not always have the `Data` member with size of 548*200. This number is a maximum. But seems that that GenericMethod I use, always try to create the struct with that Data always 548*200, and then it will obviously throw an AccessViolation because the data to be mapped has ended already.

For example this code:

```
var bytes = new byte[26];
var structure = ByteArrayToStructure<TRANS_RECORD_DATA>(bytes);
```

Should return a `TRANS_RECORD_DATA` with all those int members with 0 value, and finally that `byte[] Data` would have only the remaining two bytes. (26 - 24 = 2). But it seems that it tries to create the full 548*200 byte[] all the time, and then cause the access violation.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: That can't work of course.  Simply declare the struct *without* the Data element.  You can access the data directly from the *bytes[]* argument.  It starts at index 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you explaining it, regardless of C definition for Data array being 200*548 bytes long, it is not actually fully allocated or filled by an external unmanaged code you call.

this way your only workaround is NOT to define Data in your C# struct definition:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
struct TRANS_RECORD_DATA {
    public int size, code;
    public int ThrowItemCount;
    public int ItemCount;
    public int ItemSubStart;
    public int DataSize;
};
```

and after reading DataSize re-interpret remainder of the byte array as that data structure.

you can still use series of calls to Marshal.PtrToStructure:

```
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
TRANS_RECORD_DATA  stuff = (TRANS_RECORD_DATA) Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof (TRANS_RECORD_DATA));
var items = new List<sRECORD_ITEM>(stuff.ItemCount);
for (int i = 0; i < stuff.ItemCount; ++i)
{
    var ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject().Add(i*548)
    sRECORD_ITEM item = (sRECORD_ITEM)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr,typeof(sRECORD_ITEM));
}
```

I am pretty sure this should do the trick.

Comment: Well, not what I expected but it did the trick. I was hoping I can find a way to do this but still declaring the byte[] in the struct. Thank you.